# using toward and propercase function in crystal report

Tags: replace, crystal-reports, report

how to convert this amount in words using towords function in crystal reports e.g 1365.54 i am using this formula:

```
replace(replace (PROPERCASE(towords({EmployeePayments.ActualPayTP})),'100','Pence'),'/','')
```

and it is giving me One Thousand Three Hundred Sixty-Five And 54 Pence, but i want to have One Thousand Three Hundred Sixty-Five and 54 Pence only.

Comment: You want to append `only` at the end

Comment: hi, thanks, not end , but    and  starting with lowercase   a.

Comment: Didn't understand your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another 'replace' function then append 'only' as follows:

`replace(replace(replace(PROPERCASE(towords({EmployeePayments.ActualPayTP})),'100','Pence'),'/',''), ' And', ' and') + ' only'`